How to add a third-party plugin in Quasar Framework (using SPA)?
I'd like to use the VueFire Vue Plugin in a Quasar project. I'm using Quasar as SPA application.
VueFire's documentation suggest installing it like this:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { VueFire, VueFireAuth } from 'vuefire'
import App from './App.vue'
// the file we created above with `database`, `firestore` and other exports
import { firebaseApp } from './firebase'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueFire, {
  // imported above but could also just be created here
  firebaseApp,
  modules: [
    // we will see other modules later on
    VueFireAuth(),
  ],
})

How to integrate properly VueFire in a Quasar SPA Application?

You can probably follow the same kind of setup with this syntax: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/boot-files#anatomy-of-a-boot-file
